# DataRangePicker showing wrong date or not applying the selected date

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-plugins, daterangepicker

I'm trying to use the bootstrap dateRangePicker with the code bellow:

```
$('.dateRangePicker').daterangepicker({
    "locale": {
        "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
        "fromLabel": "De",
        "toLabel": "Até",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "daysOfWeek": ["Dom","Seg","Ter","Qua","Qui","Sex","Sáb"],
        "monthNames": ["Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"],
        "firstDay": 0
        }
    }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
});
```

With the code above, the value of the field will be changed to today just after the plugin initiate.
if i put `"autoUpdateInput" : false` the value won't be changed automatically to today, but will not receive any changes at all.

ps.: this code are for **pt-br** format.

Comment: Can you share the link of plugin?

Comment: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Do you want nothing to be selected in the start?

Comment: no. The value must be what comes from java's back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `"autoUpdateInput" : false`

and then capturing `apply.daterangepicker` and `hide.daterangepicker` events to set the value based on selection when user clicks on the apply button or clicks outside the daterangepicker to hide it.

See the code below:

```js
$('.dateRangePicker').daterangepicker({
  "autoUpdateInput": false,
  "locale": {
    "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    "separator": " - ",
    "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
    "fromLabel": "De",
    "toLabel": "Até",

    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "daysOfWeek": ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
    "monthNames": ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
    "firstDay": 0
  }
});

$('.dateRangePicker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});

$('.dateRangePicker').on('hide.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});


$('.dateRangePicker').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val('');
});
```

```css
.dateRangePicker {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input class="dateRangePicker" value="">
```